# Cannot instantiate the type for class object (Java)

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

Here's the code where I'm receiving the error (at the second "Killer" after "new").

```
String[] classes = new String[5];

kills[0] = "Brian Moser";
kills[1] = "James Doakes";
kills[2] = "Lila Tourney";
kills[3] = "Miguel Prado";

Killer morgan = new Killer("Dexter", 
                   "Morgan", 
                   kills,
                   4.0,
                   "Arthur Mitchell",
                   3,
                   false);
```

This has been giving me quite a bit of trouble, as I see no reason why this declaration should work based on my constructor for Killer.

And here's the Killer class:

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Killer{

public String firstName; 
public String lastName;
private String[] killList;
private double score;
private String nemesis;
private int accidents;
public boolean caught;

public Killer(String firstName, 
            String lastName, 
            String[] killList, 
            double score,
            String nemesis, 
            int accidents, 
            boolean caught) 
{
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    this.killList[i] = killList[i];
                this.score = score;
                this.nemesis = nemesis;
                this.accidents = accidents;
                this.caught = caught;
} //end constructor
```

I know this probably has a simple solution, but as of now, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: The `Killer` class is abstract. This is the reason you can't instantiate it. Check out [this reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) for more info on abstract classes in Java.

Comment: Change to `new Killer("Dexter", 
                   "Morgan", 
                   kills,
                   4.0,
                   "Arthur Mitchell",
                   3,
                   false){}` and it'll suddenly work.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik isn't that dirty? :-)

Comment: @MichaelAnthonyLeber When you add code, please make sure that it does not mistakes such as mismatch in the class and constructor name.

Comment: +1 for Dexter reference.

Comment: Class name is User but Constructor method is Killer. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Henrik You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

following are few main points about abstract classes

1. An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract.
2. It may or may not include abstract methods.
3. Abstract classes cannot be **instantiated**, but they can be subclassed
4. Abstract classes does not contains any constructor

in your case there is a abstract class declared as **public abstract class Killer** so as its declaration defines that it is **public**, **abstract class** with named as **Killer** so as it is stated earlier that **an Abstract classes cannot be instantiated** so you need to subclass it or remove abstract keyword in order to get its instance for further [read oracle docs abstract classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Answer (score 2):

We can't instantiate abstract class. It's characteristics of abstract class. Here it's abstract so.