# How to get 2d array from inputfile looks like field

Tags: java, file-io

I want to read a file from input this file looks like:

```
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

I want this input file, read and put in a two dimensional array.

I already tried this:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give the input filename");
    String fileName=scanner.nextLine();
    readFieldFile(fileName);

    scanner.close();
  }
  static Cell[][] readFieldFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
    char[][] field=new char[4][10];
    String currentLine;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
      while((currentLine=reader.readLine())!=null) {
        field[i]=currentLine.toCharArray();
      }
    }
    return field;
  }
```

It gives an error, but I think it is because I use `Cell[][]`. I need it to return this `Cell[][]`, so I can use it in my other functions. Does someone know how to get the right return? The field is fixed: row of 4 and columns of 10.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from char[][] to Cell[][]

Comment: What is Cell Object?

Answer (score 1):

You compute `field`, a `char[][]`, but declare that you return a `Cell[][]`. Create a `Cell[][]` of the appropriate size, and set the values as needed. Then, your errors will go away:

```
static Cell[][] readFieldFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    ... //whatever previous logic
    // don't return, though. Instead, do the following:
    Cell[][] cells = new Cell[4][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            cells[i][j] = new Cell(field[i][j]); // or however you initialize Cell
        }
    }
    return cells;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just convert the return type to be `char[][]`, by changing the method declaration:

```
static char[][] readFieldFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    ... // whatever was there already
}
```

P.S.: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) for next time. The title is fine, but asking "Can someone help me?" at any point in the question is usually imprecise enough to get you redirected to this link.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes sense what you answered. But in the line`cells[i][j] = new Cell(field[i][j]);` it says, "cannot instantiate the type Cell". Do you know how to fix this? And what this error means?

Comment: Cell is [probably an interface/abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157462/cannot-instantiate-the-type-for-class-object-java), then. Please provide the code for Cell (if it's defined). If it's not defined, you have your problem right there.

Comment: The Class Cell is very short: `package gameoflife; public enum Cell {  DEAD, LIVE }`. So why can't it instantiate? I have read the link, but can not find an answer

Comment: @mathew You can't instantiate an enum from a public constructor. Instead, based on the char, put the appropriate value into `cells`. For example, supposing it was `o` and `.` for LIVE/DEAD cells, you could do: `if(field[i][j] == 'o'){cells[i][j] = Cell.LIVE;}else if(field[i][j]=='.'){cells[i][j] = Cell.DEAD;}else{throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal input! Char is: '"+field[i][j]+"'");}`

Comment: Ah thank you!! I understand. but how does it read the input file right now? Or do I have to keep my while-loop? It says that `reader` is now not used

Comment: "... //whatever previous logic" means your while loop, yes. You do need everything that was there already, except for the `return field` statement. Then, you append my logic, and replace the assignment with the assignment logic from my previous comment.

Comment: Okay I have done this, but now, when I run it and try to print the array, it goes to the 'else' statement, and gives the throw exception.. How is this possible? Is there something wrong with my while-loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200667/discussion-between-avi-and-mathew).