# Failed to build quarkus application: Unsatisfied dependency for type

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm trying to port a small corporate (multi module) RESTEasy JAX-RS application to Quarkus, but I'm hitting the error below. There a are a number of dependency on corporate modules over which I have no control, but I tried to follow Quarkus' context and dependency injection guide (https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference).

OS: `Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL)`

Java: `OpenJDK 11.0.8`

Command: `./mvnw clean install -DskipTests`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.9.2.Final:build (default) on project <REDACTED>: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 4 deployment problems:
...
[ERROR] [3] Unsatisfied dependency for type <REDACTED>.security.cryptography.CryptographyService and qualifiers [@Default]
[ERROR]         - java member: <REDACTED>.request.handlers.ConfigurationFileDownloadHandler#cryptographyService
[ERROR]         - declared on CLASS bean [types=[<REDACTED>.request.handlers.ConfigurationFileDownloadHandler, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=<REDACTED>.request.handlers.ConfigurationFileDownloadHandler]
```

The DI in the code itself:

```
...
import <REDACTED>.security.cryptography.CryptographyService;
...

@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationFileDownloadHandler {

...

    @Inject
    private CryptographyService cryptographyService;
...
```

The dependency is declared in the sub-module pom file (as visible from `mvn dependency:tree` below):

```
[INFO] +- <REDACTED>.security.cryptography:cryptography-service-api-jar:jar:1.5.1:compile
```

I also created an `application.properties` file under `<sub-module/src/main/resources` with the following content:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.cryptography.group-id=<REDACTED>.security.cryptography
quarkus.index-dependency.cryptography.artifact-id=cryptography-service-api-jar
```

There is also an empty `beans.xml` file under ``<sub-module/src/main/resources/META-INF`.

Am I right to think that those third-party corporate classes don't have the proper annotation to be discovered by the Quarkus CDI process?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I right to think that those third-party corporate classes don't have the proper annotation to be discovered by the Quarkus CDI process?

Yes, this should be the issue, if no CDI annotation is present in the `CryptographyService` even if it's indexed by Jandex it will not be injectable.

The solution for this is to create a producer to produce a `CryptographyService` bean inside the bean factory.

Something like this:

```
@Singleton
public class CryptographyServiceProducer {
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public CryptographyService cryptographyService() {
        return new CryptographyService();
    }
}
```

For reference, there is some documentation on CDI bean producer here: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#q-ok-you-said-that-there-are-several-kinds-of-beans

Comment: Thanks @loicmathieu, very useful suggestion. I created I new `CryptographyServiceProducer` class with the code you suggested (plus imports of course), but not I see the error `Cannot instantiate the type CryptographyServiceJava(16777373)` on the line `return new CryptographyService();` Seems like a pretty basic issue, but no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, the issue might be that CryptographyService() is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157462/cannot-instantiate-the-type-for-class-object-java . I'll have to check if I have access to that source code to verify if this is indeed the case.

Comment: So `CryptographyService` is an not an abstract class, but an interface, which is the same difference, as it cannot be instantiated. I also found the implementation in a different module - `public class CryptographyServiceBean implements CryptographyService` - can I instantiate that instead?

Comment: @EmilDimitrov your issue now seems really Java related and not Quarkus related, as your CryptographyService comes from one of your library I have now idea how to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @loicmathieu, you're right, I'll try to figure out this one by myself.